# Capistrano 3 deployment broke for some reason

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, capistrano, rvm1-capistrano3

Okay,

I'm running into some weird issue with our deployment no longer working anymore. I cannot track everything that changed, but I'm hoping someone can help me out with debugging this issue and find out what is going wrong.

**deploy.rb**

```
# config valid only for current version of Capistrano    
lock '3.4.0'

set :application, 'app_name'
set :repo_url, 'github_url'
set :deploy_to, '/home/user/path'

# Source Control Configuration
set :scm, :git
# Produces: Please enter the name of the branch. (develop):
set(:branch, ask('the name of the branch.', 'develop'))

# Ask whether we want to perform a backup.
# Produces: Please enter whether to perform a backup of the database? (Y):
set(:backup, ask('whether to perform a backup of the database?', 'Y'))

puts("setting branch to: #{fetch(:branch)}")

set :user, 'my_user'

set :assets_roles, [:web, :app, :vm]
set :keep_assets, 2

set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push('.chamber.pem', 'Procfile', '.env')
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('data', 'tmp', 'log', 'uploads')

set :keep_releases, 10

set :bundle_path, nil
set :bundle_binstubs, nil
set :bundle_flags, '--system'

set :rvm1_map_bins, fetch(:rvm1_map_bins, []).push('honeybadger')

# Slack integration options
set :slack_via_slackbot, Settings.slack.via_slackbot
set :slack_team, Settings.slack.team
set :slack_token, Settings.slack.token
set :slack_icon_emoji, -> { Settings.slack.icon_emoji }
set :slack_channel, -> { Settings.slack.channel }
set :slack_username, -> { Settings.slack.username }
set :slack_run_starting, -> { Settings.slack.run_starting }
set :slack_run_finished, -> { Settings.slack.run_finished }
set :slack_run_failed, -> { Settings.slack.run_failed }
set :slack_msg_finished, -> { "@channel #{ENV['USER'] || ENV['USERNAME']} has deployed branch *#{fetch :branch}* of #{fetch :application} to *#{fetch :rails_env}*." }
set :slack_msg_failed, -> { "#{ENV['USER'] || ENV['USERNAME']} failed to deploy branch #{fetch :branch} of #{fetch :application} to #{fetch :rails_env, 'production'}." }

# Rake config
SSHKit.config.command_map[:rake] = 'bundle exec rake'

before 'deploy:started', 'deploy:rm:stop'
after 'deploy:rm:stop', 'deploy:rm:backup'
after 'deploy:finished', 'deploy:rm:start'
after 'deploy:migrate', 'deploy:rm:seed
```

**Capfile**

```
# Load DSL and set up stages
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
require 'rvm1/capistrano3'  # Do not use capistrano/bundler
require 'whenever/capistrano'
require 'capistrano/honeybadger'
require 'slackistrano/capistrano'

# Load custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks` if you have any defined
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }

require 'net/ssh/proxy/command'
def vm(tunnel:, tunnel_user: fetch(:user), vm_user: fetch(:user))
  server "#{fetch(:stage)}-vm01", {
    roles: [:vm],
    # The user on the VM
    user: vm_user,
    ssh_options: {
      # The user on the machine we're tunneling through
      proxy: Net::SSH::Proxy::Command.new("ssh #{tunnel_user}@#{tunnel} -W %h:%p"),
    }
  }
end
```

So I can run the `cap` command locally, and it does part of the work. Had some issues first with the new sprockets, but now it's complaining about the following when it needs to precompile the assets:

```
INFO [21eca199] Running bundle exec rake assets:precompile as riskmethods@playground.riskmethods.net DEBUG [21eca199] Command: cd /home/riskmethods/riskmethods/releases/20160212152030 && ( export RAILS_ENV="playground" ; bundle exec rake assets:precompile ) 
DEBUG [2eac7a5b] Finished in 0.078 seconds with exit status 0 (successful). 
INFO [4b29f0c4] Running bundle exec rake assets:precompile as riskmethods@playground-vm01 
DEBUG [4b29f0c4] Command: cd /home/riskmethods/riskmethods/releases/20160212152030 && ( export RAILS_ENV="playground" ; bundle exec rake assets:precompile ) 
DEBUG [21eca199]        bash: bundle: command not found 
 (Backtrace restricted to imported tasks) 
 cap aborted! 
  SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as riskmethods@playground.riskmethods.net: rake exit status: 127
  rake stdout: Nothing written 
  rake stderr: bash: bundle: command not found


  SSHKit::Command::Failed:
  rake exit status: 127 
  rake stdout: Nothing written 
  rake stderr: bash: bundle: command not found

  Tasks: TOP => deploy:assets:precompile
  (See full trace by running task with --trace)
  The deploy has failed with an error: 
    Exception while executing as riskmethods@playground.riskmethods.net: 
    rake exit status: 127 
    rake stdout: Nothing written 
    rake stderr: bash: bundle: command not found 

DEBUG [4b29f0c4]        bash: bundle: command not found
```

Comment: Is this a new server, or existing server?

Comment: existing server. Problem started roughly 1 week ago

Comment: It's happening here too, I can't use bundler and assets compile with capistrano

Answer (score 0):

As your error message saying `bash: bundle: command not found`

It seems you dont have the gem `bundler` installed on the server

install bundler gem on server by running the following command that should do the trick

`gem install bundler`

Comment: bundler is installed on the server. SSH'ing into the box and running commands manually works just fine.